# Recursive Division Random Maze Generation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, maze

I'm currently doing a project where I want to randomly generate mazes for a game. After studying performance levels etc for maze generation I've decided to use the Recursive Division method. Whilst the explanation of the algorithm is somewhat understandable I'm struggling to formulate the algorithm in a pseudo format so that I can understand it fully and begin coding it. Can someone help me with a detailed explanation of the process or some pseudo-code? All help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** From what I understand I will need to decide whether to divide horizontally or vertically. How is this decision made and what is the process of this division with regards to starting point and finishing point?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Bex From what I understand I will need to decide whether to divide horizontally or vertically. How is this decision made and what is the process of this division with regards to starting point and finishing point? Apologies if question is vague if this helps more I will edit the question to include this detail

Comment: Jamis Buck made an excellent maze creation blog series. His post on Recursive Division Maze Generation is very good and easy to read.
http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Begin with an empty field.
2. Bisect the field with a wall, either horizontally or vertically. Add a single passage through the wall.
3. Repeat step #2 with the areas on either side of the wall.
4. Continue, recursively, until the maze reaches the desired resolution.

[Jamis Buck on Maze Generation: Recursive Backtracking](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm)

Comment: The bisection would literally be just selecting a single row or column then? Then temporarily store each side as a new 2d array and bisect that until resolution is reached? Would you advise  erasing the passage as part of these steps or wait until after all walls have been created?  EDIT: Actually scrap the temp 2d array idea that would at the very least be extremely messy if even possible at all.

Comment: Store the complete maze as a 2d array. At the beginning the maze is empty and the algorithm adds and removes walls until it reaches the integer limit. Each element contains information of if there's a wall the to the south and/or a wall to the east. You can use `0b01` and `0b10` and some bit masking to represent the walls.